# VBA MS Access bind ADO recordset to server side cursor

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to bind ADO recordset from SQL Server to Form but cursor to be on server side. If I use adUseClient, working fine, but I can't find way to use adUseServer. Any help would be appreciated.

This is working code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset, strConnString As String
    strConnString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=DIMITRIPC;DATABASE=NORTHWIND;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    cnn.connectionString = strConnString
    cnn.Open
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
    cmd.CommandText = "Products" '"SELECT dbo.Products.* FROM dbo.Products"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdTable
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADOdB.recordset")
    rst.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rst.Open cmd, , adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic
    Set Me.Recordset = rst
End Sub
```

Comment: Urgh why would you want to use a cursor? And what's the question exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: Have you tried a different cursor type? Generally, you use `adOpenDynamic` for server-side cursors/when you want to see changes, and `adOpenStatic` for client-side cursors/when you don't want to see changes. `adOpenKeyset` is an in-between finicky cursor type, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/keyset-cursors.

Comment: I did it in excel with Microsoft Activex Data Objects 2.8 Library connected to another database on SQL Server, and it works ok.
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    rst.Open cmd, , adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic
    'Set Me.Recordset = rst
    Do Until rst.EOF
        MsgBox rst!ID
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop